# Delete multiple files in CENTOS command

Tags: centos

How can i delete all the file that are ending with *0x0.jpg in CENTOS ? I need to delete multiple files nested into folders and subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a shell - try

```
find /mydirectory -type f -print  | grep '0x0.jpg$' | xargs -n1 rm -f
```

There is probable a more elegant solution but that should work

However I would put an echo in before `rm` on the first run to ensure that the right files are going to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Ed Heal's answer works just fine but neither the `grep` nor `xargs` calls are necessary. The following should work just as well and be a good bit more efficient for large amounts of files.

```
find /mydirectory -name '*0x0.jpg' -type f -exec rm -rf () \+
```